# Computing the second distributional derivative of the tent function

Tags: proof-verification, distribution-theory

I recently took an exam where I had to solve the following question:

> Find the second distributional derivative of the function
>
> \begin{equation}
> u(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1 - |x|, \quad |x| < 1, \\ 
> 0, \quad \quad \quad \; \;|x| > 1
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Here's my solution:

Note that $u(x)$ is the tent function,

> \begin{equation}
> u(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1 - x, \quad 0 \leq x < 1, \\
> 1 + x, \quad -1 < x \leq 0, \\ 
> 0 \quad  \quad \quad  \; |x| > 1
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

We show that the second distributional derivative, $D^{2}u = 0$ almost everywhere. Let $\phi$ be a test function (compactly supported, continuous function) in $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $u$ is a locally integrable function, $u$ defines a distribution by its action on the set of all test function. Hence,

\begin{align}
(Du)(\phi) := \langle Du, \phi \rangle & = - \langle u , \phi' \rangle  \\
& = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \phi'(x) dx \\
& = - \Bigg [ \phi(x)u(x) \Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}   - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u'(x) \phi(x) dx  \Bigg ] \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u'(x) \phi(x) dx, \quad \quad \; \text{since} \; \phi(x) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})  \\
& = \int_{-1}^{0} (1) \phi(x) dx + \int_{0}^{1} (-1) \phi(x) dx 
\end{align}
where,
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1, \quad \quad \; \; 0 \leq x < 1, \\
1 \quad -1 \leq x < 0, \\
0 \quad \quad \quad |x| > 1, \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
in the sense of distribution. This shows that $Du = f(x)$. By a similar integration by parts calculation, we can show that, $D^{2}u = D(Du) = Df = 0$ almost everywhere:

\begin{align}
(D(Du))(\phi) := \langle Df, \phi \rangle & = - \langle f , \phi' \rangle  \\
& = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \phi'(x) dx \\
& = - \Bigg [ f(x)u(x) \Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}   - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) \phi(x) dx  \Bigg ] \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) \phi(x) dx, \quad \quad \; \text{since} \; \phi(x) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})  \\
& = \int_{-1}^{0} (0) \phi(x) dx + \int_{0}^{1} (0) \phi(x) dx = 0 = \langle Df , 0 \rangle 
\end{align}

This proves the claim.

I scored 4/10 on this problem, and I can't seem to figure out my mistake. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm admittedly a bit rusty on my distributional derivatives, but this looks fine to me.  My only thought is that maybe the grader wanted to actually see the "similar integration by parts calculation"?

Comment: The second distributional derivative is not zero.  It has some Dirac-$\delta$s.

Comment: Because it is continuous and piecewise $C^1$ the derivative of $(1-|x|) 1_{|x| < 1}$ is $(1-|x|)' 1_{|x| < 1} =- \text{sign}(x) 1_{|x| < 1} $, the latter is piecewise constant with 3 jumps so its derivative is $\delta(x+1)- 2 \delta(x)+\delta(x-1)$

Comment: @DMcMor If $Df=0$ then $f$ is constant.

Comment: Ah yes.  As I said, just a bit rusty.

Comment: The second integration by parts is simply wrong. The first integration by parts, where you show $Du=f$, is right, but it should probably be justified. You could note that $u$ is absolutely continuous and quote the relevant theorem, or you could just split the original integral into $\int_{-1}^0+\int_0^1$ and integrate by parts twice. The second approach has the advantage that it doesn't require anything fancy, just integration by parts for $C^1$ functions..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $D\phi=f$, where $f$ is what you said. It's clear that $f'=0$ almost everywhere, but that does *not* imply that the distributional derivative $Df$ vanishes!  It doesn't. (It would be right if $Df$ were defined by a locally integrable function...)

**Hint** regarding a correct calculation of $Df$: Say $g=\chi_{[0,1]}$ (so $g'=0$ almost everywhere). If $\phi$ is a test function then $$-\int g\phi'=-\int_0^1 \phi'=\phi(0)-\phi(1).$$So $Dg=\delta_0-\delta_1$.

Comment: Right, why isn't $Df$ locally integrable, if I may ask, which is what I assume makes the integration by parts calculation fail? But don't you use the fact that $g$ is locally integrable to define its action on $\phi$ via the integral. This leaves me a bit confused, but I can understand your calculation. I'm just not sure why my otherwise incorrect computation is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, $f$ and $g$ are locally integrable. That (evidently) has nothing too  do with $Df$ and $Dg$ being locally integrable. $Dg$ isn't because it's $\delta_0-\delta_1$. Not a very good "why not", but it's the best available - it's not because it's not.

Comment: "I'm just not sure why my otherwise incorrect computation is incorrect": hard to say if  you don't show us what it looks like...

Comment: No. I meant to say that $f$ and $g$ are locally integrable, where $f =Du$ in my problem. Since $Du = f$ is locally integrable, I (blindly) set up the integration by parts problem again (which I have now added to the post) and argued $D^{2}u = Df = 0$. What seems to be wrong with my computation? I understand your point, though, the $Df$ must involve the delta distributions, which can be seen if we write $f$ as a linear combination of the Heaviside distributions.

Comment: " Since Df is locally integrable,": no, $Df$ is _not_ locally iintegrable! A diistribution $v$ is said to be locally integrable if there exists $h\in L^1{loc}$ with $v(\phi)  = \int h\phi$ for every test function $\phi$.

Comment: Why  your argument is wrong:  The integration by parts isn't right. Why  not? Why do you think it _is_  right? Whatever theorem you're using to justify it, the hypotheses are not satisfied. Again, hard to say why it's not valid since you don't say why you thought it _was_ valid...

Comment: Hmm, useful fact. Say $f$ is locally integrable.  The distribution derivative $Df$ is locally integrable if and only if $f$ is locally absolutely continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused. I edit my post. I meant to say that "Since $Du = f$ is locally integrable..."

Comment: Well, $f$ locally integrable simply does not imply that iiintegration by parts is correct. Why not, it simply doesn't - you haven't seen any theorems saying it works.

Comment: Most likely. I simply relied on the definition twice that a locally integrable function defines a distribution by integrating it w.r.t. a test function.

Comment: Ok, someone explain what the problem is...

Comment: I probably don’t know all the key theorems in disruption theory. I just have a working knowledge of how to compute distributional derivatives, hence the mistakes I guess.

Comment: I didn't mean that problem, I was wondering why the downvote...

Comment: Hi, so I have a question: suppose I have a function with a jump discontinuity. Let’s take $f(x)$ to be $0 for x < 0$ and $x+1$ for $x$ greater than equal to 0. Will it’s distributional derivative involve the Dirac delta Distribution or will it be the Heaviside distribution. An integration by parts calculation will give me the Heaviside distribution, whereas if I write $f(x)$ as $H(x) + 1$, where H is the Heaviside distribution, I’ll get a Dirac delta. Naturally, I’m confused.

Comment: It's the sum of $\delta_0$ and the Heaviside function. You made an error somewhere in your integration by parts: $-\int f\phi'=-\int_0^\infty (x+1)\phi'(x)\,dx=\phi(0)+\int_0^\infty\phi.$

Comment: Btw $f\ne H+1$; in fact $f(x)=H(x)(x+1)$.